# Test Driven .NET won't use NUnit addins

Tags: .net, nunit, testdriven.net, nunit-addins

I am experiencing a problem with running NUnit via the Test Driven .NET plugin with Visual Studio 2008.  I have an addin that when I use the NUnit GUI, works just fine.  However, the addin doesn't seem to work when run NUnit through TDD.NET.  I've tried a few things, such as updating to the lastest version, and placing the addin into TDD.NET's copy of NUnit, and modifying the TDD.NET nunit.config file to point at another copy nunit.  None of these strategies work.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be helpful to know what addin(s) you are using. Looking at the [NUnit Addin docs](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunitAddins&r=2.5.10) there are several different types of addins, and it may be, for example, that GUI addins aren't loaded from TDD.NET. Just a WAG.

Comment: @SteveDonie good point!. It's a `EventListeners` addin, it does nothing related to GUI.

Comment: I experienced sort of the same issue with xunit, when the dlls Ive tried to use were "blocked" because they have been downloaded from an untrusted location. Did you verify yours are unblocked?

Comment: If TestDriven runs in a 32bit process, try to run it in x64 (or the other way around)... 99% of the world problems are bitness related :-)
Tools -> Options -> TestDriven.Net -> Any CPU Tests

Answer (score 1):

check following things :

> 1) make sure your cursor is inside the test method of the test class.
>   2) make sure you view build panel and in the top combo box the value
>   build is present. Make sure u change the build value to test.

And see if any test result is visible  also try reading documentation of the plugin

http://www.testdriven.net/quickstart.aspx

Answer (score -1):

try running  nunit-console.exe as a post build script of your project property. It executes automatically after each build.